# Value from th:text nested in th:action in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to use a value from car.id in the th:action. This code below redirects the user to the page of a car with id 1, so I want to replace the "1" with "${car.id}":

```
               <p th:text="${car.id}" />
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/cars:1}" method="get">
                    <p><input type="submit" value="car panel"  /></p>
                </form>
```

I tried it with:

```
           <form action="#" th:action="@{/cars:"${car.id}"}" method="get">
```

but unfortunately it does not work. How can I pass the value?

Here is how it is displayed on the site:
[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Eabr.png)

Comment: When you say it doesnt work, what the URL gets created for action ?

Comment: It has worked with the solution of Metroids, but thank you :)

Comment: That’s great, Mark that as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The page on Thymeleaf's [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) has examples for this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/cars:{id}(id=${car.id})}" method="get">
```